# Embjerjs store.find not working while getJSON is

Tags: json, ember.js, ember-data

I'm starting to build an ember app. I'm almost done with the API, which I know works. I'm able to properly display with .getJSON but not with the store.find method, instead I get an unknown type error, which i'm guessing amounts to the data not being properly retrieved. I am using ember inspector in Chrome, but I don't see where it's trying to get the JSON, i'm assuming it should be "api/projects".

thanks!

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('projects')
});

App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'api'
});

App.Projects = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string')
});
```

this works:

```
App.ProjectsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function(){
     return $.getJSON("api/projects").then(function(data){
       return data.projects;
     });
    }
 });
```

this does not:

```
App.ProjectsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function(){
     return this.store.find('projects');
    }
 });
```

ERROR:

```
Error while processing route: projects Cannot read property 'typeKey' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'typeKey' of undefined

at DS.RESTAdapter.DS.Adapter.extend.findAll (http://trgmanage.app/js/libs/ember-data.min.js:9:28455)
at Object.Ember.assert (http://trgmanage.app/js/libs/ember-1.10.0.debug.js:3934:27)
at DS.Store.Ember.Object.extend.fetchAll (http://trgmanage.app/js/libs/ember-data.min.js:8:20000)
at DS.Store.Ember.Object.extend.findAll (http://trgmanage.app/js/libs/ember-data.min.js:8:19773)
at DS.Store.Ember.Object.extend.find (http://trgmanage.app/js/libs/ember-data.min.js:8:16174)
at App.ProjectsRoute.Ember.Route.extend.model (http://trgmanage.app/js/app.js:13:23)
at EmberObject.extend.deserialize (http://trgmanage.app/js/libs/ember-1.10.0.debug.js:23915:21)
at applyHook (http://trgmanage.app/js/libs/ember-1.10.0.debug.js:50118:30)
at Object.HandlerInfo.runSharedModelHook (http://trgmanage.app/js/libs/ember-1.10.0.debug.js:48139:22)
at Object.subclass.getModel (http://trgmanage.app/js/libs/ember-1.10.0.debug.js:48365:21)
```

JSON Response: (Formatted by JSONview in Chrome)

```
{
projects: [
{
id: 1,
title: "this is going",
description: "Aspernatur eum placeat consequuntur. Hic totam molestias nemo. Aut et aut aut earum deserunt impedit. Voluptatum omnis quae est corporis dicta voluptas ut quod. Laboriosam impedit sed eos ut rerum aliquid."
},
{
id: 2,
title: "twinkle1",
description: "Atque nihil ratione dolorem neque odio ex. Facere eaque veritatis incidunt veniam vitae. Culpa voluptatum accusamus voluptate voluptate aut nihil. Sunt adipisci deleniti nihil quia dolorem. Dolor nemo et explicabo minima eos iusto autem. Non qui eveniet rem aliquid et."
},
{
id: 3,
title: "Culpa quibusdam perspiciatis id dolorem consequuntur.",
description: "Ut veritatis nihil ducimus consequuntur nulla. Facilis qui error enim iste soluta dolore. Optio accusamus aliquam dicta. Voluptatem sint dolores quaerat quam ut. Deleniti iste quae molestias amet velit."
}
   ]
}
```

JSON Response unformatted:

```
{"projects":[{"id":1,"title":"this is going","description":"Aspernatur eum placeat consequuntur. Hic totam molestias nemo. Aut et aut aut earum deserunt impedit. Voluptatum omnis quae est corporis dicta voluptas ut quod. Laboriosam impedit sed eos ut rerum aliquid."},{"id":2,"title":"twinkle1","description":"Atque nihil ratione dolorem neque odio ex. Facere eaque veritatis incidunt veniam vitae. Culpa voluptatum accusamus voluptate voluptate aut nihil. Sunt adipisci deleniti nihil quia dolorem. Dolor nemo et explicabo minima eos iusto autem. Non qui eveniet rem aliquid et."},{"id":3,"title":"Culpa quibusdam perspiciatis id dolorem consequuntur.","description":"Ut veritatis nihil ducimus consequuntur nulla. Facilis qui error enim iste soluta dolore. Optio accusamus aliquam dicta. Voluptatem sint dolores quaerat quam ut. Deleniti iste quae molestias amet velit."}]}
```

Comment: Can you please post the exact error and stack trace that you get?

Comment: What does your *Projects* serializer look like?

Comment: I don't have one, do i need one? My json follows the correct format

Comment: The network tab in the Chrome debugger displays all Ajax requests that are being sent over. That would be a good place to start (to see at least if your request is being sent and if it is sent on the correct URL). Also, if you could provide us with a sample of your JSON payload that would help too (it may be formatted in a way that Ember Data does not like).

Comment: Its funny, when using the store.find method, I don't see any network requests for it. I only see it when using .getJSON

Answer (score 0):

oops. was using an older version of ember-data beta 6. yikes. After updating to the latest beta 15, everything works as it should.